# How do I get the list of a node relationships which is ordered by the properties of the relationship?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to get a list of nodes's relationships which is ordered by relationship's properties.
For example, I have two labels for my nodes which are Org and Company, there is only one relationship type between them which is INVEST_IN. The INVEST_IN relationship has a property "Series" which could be "Series A","Series B","Series C"
So the graph is like as followed:

```
merge (o:Org{name:'Google'})
merge (o2:Org{name:'Facebook'})
merge (c:Company{name:'Company1'})
merge (c2:Company{name:'Company2'})
merge (o)-[:INVEST_IN{series:'A'}]-(c)
merge (o)-[:INVEST_IN{series:'B'}]-(c)
merge (o)-[:INVEST_IN{series:'C'}]-(c)
merge (o)-[:INVEST_IN{series:'A'}]-(c2)
merge (o)-[:INVEST_IN{series:'B'}]-(c2)
merge (o2)-[:INVEST_IN{series:'C'}]-(c)
merge (o2)-[:INVEST_IN{series:'B'}]-(c2)
merge (o2)-[:INVEST_IN{series:'C'}]-(c2)
```

[image]

So I need the result like:

Org              ordered_series

Google           [A,B,C]
Facebook         [C,B]

The result is ordered by the number of series of each Org's relationship.
Google has 2 A series, 2 B series, 1 C series, so the result is [A,B,C]
Facebook has 1 B series and 2 C series so the result is [C,B]

```
match (o:Org)-[r:INVEST_IN]->(c:Company)
return o.name, r.series, count(r.series)
```

return the [image]

and I do not understand the difference between

```
match (o:Org)-[r:INVEST_IN]->(c:Company)
return o.name, r.series, count(r.series)
```

and

```
match (o:Org)-[r:INVEST_IN]->(c:Company)
with o, r, count(r.series) as cr
return o.name, r.series, cr
```

They are so different. I could not order the relationship and collect them.
Can anyone show me how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2 queries are logically the same, as long as `Org` nodes have unique `name` values.

This query:

```
MATCH (o:Org)-[r:INVEST_IN]->(c:Company)
RETURN o.name AS name, r.series AS series, COUNT(r.series) AS cnt
ORDER BY name ASC, cnt DESC
```

produces this result:

```
╒══════════╤════════╤═════╕
│"name"    │"series"│"cnt"│
╞══════════╪════════╪═════╡
│"Facebook"│"C"     │2    │
├──────────┼────────┼─────┤
│"Facebook"│"B"     │1    │
├──────────┼────────┼─────┤
│"Google"  │"A"     │2    │
├──────────┼────────┼─────┤
│"Google"  │"B"     │2    │
├──────────┼────────┼─────┤
│"Google"  │"C"     │1    │
└──────────┴────────┴─────┘
```

[UPDATE]

To get the series for each `Org` in a list:

```
MATCH (o:Org)-[r:INVEST_IN]->(c:Company)
WITH o.name AS name, r.series AS series, COUNT(r.series) AS cnt
ORDER BY name ASC, cnt DESC
RETURN name, COLLECT(series) AS seriesList
```

which produces this result:

```
╒══════════╤═════════════╕
│"name"    │"seriesList" │
╞══════════╪═════════════╡
│"Facebook"│["C","B"]    │
├──────────┼─────────────┤
│"Google"  │["A","B","C"]│
└──────────┴─────────────┘
```